# Need Explanation on ElasticSearch Filters Aggregation

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm trying to understand the syntax of Filters Aggregations in ElasticSearch, and I'm stumped. The example given in the documentation is this:

```json
    {
      "aggs" : {
        "messages" : {
          "filters" : {
            "filters" : {
              "errors" :   { "term" : { "body" : "error"   }},
              "warnings" : { "term" : { "body" : "warning" }}
            }
          },
          "aggs" : {
            "monthly" : {
              "histogram" : {
                "field" : "timestamp",
                "interval" : "1M"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I understand the following:

- "aggs" defines the aggregations blocks (it's a shortcut for "aggregations"). There's actually nested aggregations in the example, as can be seen.
- "messages" is the user-defined name of the aggregation block.
- "errors" and "warnings" are user-defined names of the filters used to create the "buckets" for the aggregation. They drop items with "body" equal to "error" and "warning" respectively ("term" matching).

What I don't understand is why "filters" appears twice, nested inside of itself. Per the general aggregations syntax:

```json
    "aggregations" : {
        "<aggregation_name>" : {
            "<aggregation_type>" : {
                <aggregation_body>
            }
            [,"aggregations" : { [<sub_aggregation>]+ } ]?
        }
        [,"<aggregation_name_2>" : { ... } ]*
    }
```

- "aggs" is short for "aggregations"
- "messages" is my "<aggregation name"
- "filters" is the ""

What's the second "filters" element doing? And where is it documented that "filters" has to be self-nested; it doesn't seem to be the case for any of the other aggregations I'm learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand how you feel, been there, too :-)

In the `filters` aggregation, the first `filters` occurrence is the `aggregation_type` and the second is part of the `aggregation_body`of the `filters` aggregation and is the only valid `key` that this aggregation supports.

The second `filters` occurrence could have been called anything else (`filter_list`, `list`, etc) to denote that it contains the list of filters for that aggregation, but the ES folks picked `filters` which happen to also be the same name as the name of the aggregation itself.

So it goes like this:

```
{
  "aggs" : {                    <--- key word to declare aggregations
    "messages" : {              <--- custom name for the aggregation that follows
      "filters" : {             <--- aggregation_type
        "filters" : {           <--- first (and only) key of the aggregation_body
          "errors" :   { "term" : { "body" : "error"   }},
          "warnings" : { "term" : { "body" : "warning" }}
        }
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "monthly" : {
          "histogram" : {
            "field" : "timestamp",
            "interval" : "1M"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```