# elasticsearch filters aggregation won't work

Tags: elasticsearch

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489706/need-explanation-on-elasticsearch-filters-aggregation) post, I can't get filters agg to work:

```
GET files/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "words": "sugar"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "xxx": {
      "filters": {
        "filter_list": {
          "errors": {
            "term": {
              "abstract": "error"
            }
          },
          "warnings": {
            "term": {
              "abstract": "warning"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "st": {
          "significant_terms": {
            "field": "abstract"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> SearchParseException[[files][3]: query[words:sugar],from[-1],size[-1]:
>   Parse Failure [Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [xxx]:
>   [filter_list].]]; }{[tIS8uY8nTDil6kWtgsbkQg][files][4]:
>   SearchParseException[[files][4]: query[words:sugar],from[-1],size[-1]:
>   Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n  \"query\": {\n
>   \"match\": {\n      \"words\": \"sugar\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"aggs\": {\n
>   \"xxx\": {\n      \"filters\": {\n        \"filter_list\": {\n
>   \"errors\": {\n            \"term\": {\n              \"abstract\":
>   \"error\"\n            }\n          },\n          \"warnings\": {\n
>   \"term\": {\n              \"abstract\": \"warning\"\n            }\n 
>   }\n        }\n      },\n      \"aggs\": {\n        \"st\": {\n
>   \"significant_terms\": {\n            \"field\": \"abstract\"\n
>   }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n]]]; nested:
>   SearchParseException[[epars][4]: query[words:sugar],from[-1],size[-1]:
>   Parse Failure [Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [xxx]:
>   [filter_list].]]; }]",    "status": 400 }

Answer (score 1):

You have only one thing wrong, i.e. `filter_list` should read `filters`, as it is a mandatory element of the [`filters` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html).

```
GET files/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "words": "sugar"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "xxx": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {           <---- change this
          "errors": {
            "term": {
              "abstract": "error"
            }
          },
          "warnings": {
            "term": {
              "abstract": "warning"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "st": {
          "significant_terms": {
            "field": "abstract"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Val!  Thanks for the response.  I thought, though, that you said in that post I referred to which you answered: "The second filters occurrence could have been called anything else (filter_list, list, etc) to denote that it contains the list of filters for that aggregation, but the ES folks picked filters which happen to also be the same name as the name of the aggregation itself." - What am I missing?

Comment: It means that you **have to** use `filters` twice, it's what the ES folks picked and enforced. This naming is a bit unfortunate, I'm afraid, but that's how it is.

Comment: Any chance with this?