# Elasticsearch aggregate by geo location

Tags: search, elasticsearch, search-engine

I want to group data by their location with shapes and bounding boxes. For example group the results by hemisphere:

```
GET cdc/_search
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "aggs": {
      "group_by_geo": {
         "geo_bounding_box": {
            "field": "location",
            "boxes": [
               {
                  "top_left": {
                     "lat": 90,
                     "lon": -180
                  },
                  "bottom_right": {
                     "lat": 0,
                     "lon": 0
                  }
               },
               {
                  "top_left": {
                     "lat": 90,
                     "lon": 0
                  },
                  "bottom_right": {
                     "lat": 0,
                     "lon": 180
                  }
               },
               {
                  "top_left": {
                     "lat": 0,
                     "lon": -180
                  },
                  "bottom_right": {
                     "lat": -90,
                     "lon": 0
                  }
               },
               {
                  "top_left": {
                     "lat": 0,
                     "lon": 0
                  },
                  "bottom_right": {
                     "lat": -90,
                     "lon": 180
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         "aggs": {
            "over_time": {
               "date_histogram": {
                  "field": "date",
                  "interval": "day",
                  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "AvgTemp": {
                     "avg": {
                        "field": "hits"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So the `over_time`part works fine isolated but this query gives me `"reason": "Could not find aggregator type [geo_bounding_box] in [group_by_geo]"`

My syntax is inspired by [range aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html) but apparently this is not working in this case.

Is this possible or do I have to make separate queries filtering by the 4 boxes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `geo_bounding_box` aggregation, (there's a `geo_bounding_box` filter, though).

You can achieve what you need using a [`filters`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html) aggregation containing one [`geo_bounding_box` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-bounding-box-query.html) for each bounding box. Basically something like this:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_geo": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "box1": {
            "geo_bounding_box": {
              "location": {
                "top_left": {
                  "lat": 90,
                  "lon": -180
                },
                "bottom_right": {
                  "lat": 0,
                  "lon": 0
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "box2": {
            "geo_bounding_box": {
              "location": {
                "top_left": {
                  "lat": 90,
                  "lon": 0
                },
                "bottom_right": {
                  "lat": 0,
                  "lon": 180
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "box3": {
            "geo_bounding_box": {
              "location": {
                "top_left": {
                  "lat": 0,
                  "lon": -180
                },
                "bottom_right": {
                  "lat": -90,
                  "lon": 0
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "box4": {
            "geo_bounding_box": {
              "location": {
                "top_left": {
                  "lat": 0,
                  "lon": 0
                },
                "bottom_right": {
                  "lat": -90,
                  "lon": 180
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "over_time": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "date",
            "interval": "day",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "AvgTemp": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "hits"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Why is filters doubled?

Comment: That's the way [it is defined](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html). Also see [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489706/need-explanation-on-elasticsearch-filters-aggregation/32492198#32492198) on this very subject.

Comment: Ah I get it thanks four your help seems a bit ugly and difficult at first ;)

Comment: Indeed, the second `filters` could have been named something else.